# What distribution should my data on sales follow

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

I'm a chain store and have many stores across the country that all sell a particular shampoo product P.

I have made a plot as shown in the image below. For example, 30 stores each sold 1 of P in the past two weeks. The sum of the areas of the bars is  the total number of P sold across all stores in the past two weeks.

What should be the theoretical shape of this plot? You may assume anything that gives a clean answer to this.

[image: Sales]

Comment: This question is somewhat unclear, it would be helpful to see what your graph actually looks like - is it some form of histogram? I'm not sure that "the theoretical distribution of product sales" is an answerable question.

Comment: Maybe Log-normal or Poisson distribution? You should perform statisitcal test for distribution.

Comment: Thanks for including the plot. I still don't think you can get an answer to the *theoretical* distribution, but at least it will allow people to suggest potentially suitable models.

Comment: Ultimately this is a question about how stores sell shampoo: it is not a question that statistics can legitimately answer, since there is no theory of shampoo sales in stores.  I won't deny that statistical ideas can shed light on this issue, so I will vote to reopen; but I would like to suggest that you change your question to focus on whatever your analytical objective might be so that you don't get sidetracked by such irrelevant and possibly misleading issues.

Comment: "You may assume anything that gives a clean answer to this" is not something you should encourage. There are going to be assumptions that lead to mutually exclusive "clean answers". Given that someone stipulates one of them, how will you know if it's relevant to your situation or if the answer is worse that useless & takes you down the wrong path.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @whuber the analytical objective is to see if the discrepancies in sales of this particular shampoo across the stores is statistically natural or not. The manufacturers of the shampoo insist it isn't. Also I don't think the shape of the graph is peculiar to this particular product, I have plotted the same graph for other products (like biscuits etc.) and the qualitative features look similar.

Comment: What would "statistically natural" mean?  Since there is no statistical theory of shampoo sales, it's difficult to translate that phrase into anything that can be analyzed. What we do know is that sales depend on store size, visibility, retail catchment area, pricing, surrounding demographics, local demand, advertising, and much more.  This distribution (and distributions of other products) reflect variation in those factors. If you wish to make any inferences about *this particular product* then you need to control for such factors.